# .php file type not recognized on raspberry pi

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

Brand new to pi and can't get php code to execute from .php file or when embedded in .html file.  php seems to be loaded ok (php -v returns expected blurb).  If I embed:

```
<?php echo "Hello World" ?>
```

in HTML, it seems to ignore anything inside of the php code segment.  If I try to run that same (single) line of code in a .php file, the system responds with "This text file 'index.php' seems to be an executable script.  What do you want me to do with it?"

running php 5.6 on pi 3.

Any help for this newbie would be appreciated.

Comment: "php -v returns expected blurb" That's the PHP CLI. Is PHP-CGI integrated with the webserver (probably Apache)?

Comment: I was following this tutorial:

Comment: I'm not sure how to reply to an answer.  It seems what I tried "add a comment" didn't work.

Comment: Ok, clearly no one will be able to see the link or any comments after it.  Trying again here.  The link - (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md)